# How can I assign an inputted string value to a variable?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, variables, input

`x = input("Enter roman numberal:")`

I need to enter one roman numeral as a string and return the value. When I run the code above, I get that whatever I enter in as the string isn't defined. I just want `x` to represent the inputted string, what am I doing wrong?

I am using `Python 2.7.3`.

Answer (score 1):

Use raw input

```
X = raw_input('enter value?')
```

Comment: is there anyway to do that without raw_input or is that my only option for the most part?

Comment: `input` in Python 2.x treats what you enter as a Python expression and tries to evaluate it. So, you could also just enter quotes around your Roman numeral, so it comes in as a string. However, `raw_input()` is the best solution for a lot of reasons.